# How do I cancel composed asynchronous operations in Asio?

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-asio, cancellation

I want to use the composed async operation [`asio::async_connect`](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/doc/asio/reference/async_connect.html), and cancel it, possibly between the individual calls to `basic_socket::async_connect` which it makes.

In the same manner, I'd like to cancel my own composed async operations (which use [`async_compose`](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/doc/asio/reference/async_compose.html)).

I am **not** asking how to cancel the non-composed member function [`basic_socket::async_connect`](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/doc/asio/reference/basic_socket/async_connect.html), for which I could call `basic_socket::cancel`.

The free function is composed, so while calling `cancel` on the socket might stop an ongoing `socket::async_connect`, it would not stop queued operations.

1. How do I cancel `asio::async_connect`?
2. In general, how do I cancel composed operations?
3. How do I cancel custom composed operations? (At least with this third option I could hack in some kind of cancellation token system that can check a flag between "building-block" async operations, but I still can't use existing composed operations in this case).

To summarize the problem, see this diagram from [Robert Leahy's 2019 CppCon talk](https://youtu.be/3wy1OPqNZZ8?t=1422):

[image]

This shows the issue with `async_write`, a composed operation which also has this problem.

Robert Leahy solves this by reimplementing `async_write` in a wrapper object which checks a cancellation flag before calling every atomic `async_write_some` operation on the underlying stream.

Perhaps this is the solution, but it means that I would have to re-implement every built-in composed asio operation to use this kind of similar wrapper object.

Comment: 1. I suppose you just handle `asio::error::operation_aborted` inside your `IteratorConnectHandler`. I didn't try it myself, but common sense implies that it will stop the iterations. 2. If you have a stetful object that handles your composed operation, you can additionally store an `std::atomic_bool` and check each step if you have to finish early. But for each of the asynchronous steps you'd probably will have to wait for `asio::error::operation_aborted`

Comment: [This paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2175r0.html#networking-ts-boostasio-cancellation-model), a proposed extension to the Executors TS, seems to talk about the problem I'm having: "this pattern of cancellation does not generalise well to asynchronous operations that are not methods of objects."

Comment: while it does not generalise, for the particular `asio::async_connect` function I think it would suffice. The phrase `that are not methods of objects` probably refers to *non-composed* asynchronous operations. And it is true since you would have to call static functions to modify their state in order to cancel the operation

Comment: If you want a way to cancel a non-member composed function, you can, for example, return a "canceller" from that function, which upon invocation will cancel the whole composed operation in a manner you want...

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I can handle `operation_aborted` in my ops, but that error code might never get to them--for example, `cancel()`ing the socket object during an  `asio::async_connect` (the composed one) will maybe cancel the current endpoint attempt, but if one has finished and queued the next, nothing gets cancelled and the operation happily continues (like Robert Leahy's diagram in the question). So I'd need a sticky bit, as you say, *inside* the composed op. Which would mean I'd have to re-implement every composed operation that comes with asio!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58574881/9363996

Comment: That describes the problem, certainly, and while closing the socket may work for things like `asio::async_write`, I don't know that it would be guarunteed for `asio::async_connect` (which calls `socket.close` in its loop anyways), and certainly wouldn't be a general solution for composed operations.

Comment: Would be nice if you shared some code though. I didn't use `asio::async_connect` and genuinely didn't use composed sending or receiving operations either. It seems that you have 2 ways: try to contribute and fix that issue (good luck with that), or just implement your custom stateful composed operations using `asio::async_compose`, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisiting my own question later for posterity: I think composed cancellation support is a pretty new feature and lots of this stuff is still `experimental::` as of time of writing.

As of Asio 1.19.0, if a composed op *supports* cancellation (see docs for it), it appears you're able to bind a `cancellation_slot` to it (with `bind_cancellation_slot`) and trigger that with an associated `cancellation_signal`, or by using [logical operators with `awaitables`](https://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_22_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/cpp20_coroutines.html#boost_asio.overview.composition.cpp20_coroutines.co_ordinating_parallel_coroutines) which will trigger cancellation automatically.

This process is described here in the docs: https://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_22_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/cancellation.html with this example given:

```cpp
class session
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<proxy>
{
  ...

  void do_read()
  {
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    socket_.async_read_some(
        buffer(data_),
        boost::asio::bind_cancellation_slot(
          cancel_signal_.slot(),
          [self](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t n)
          {
            ...
          }
        )
      );
  }

  ...

  void request_cancel()
  {
    cancel_signal_.emit(boost::asio::cancellation_type::total);
  }

  ...

  boost::asio::cancellation_signal cancel_signal_;
};
```

These `cancellation_slot`s/`cancellation_signal`s appear to work like fancy `std::stop_tokens`. Implementing cancellation with them in custom composed ops appears to be different depending on which method of composition you're using (`async_compose`, `experimental::co_composed`, callback chains), but the [co_composed docs](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.28.0/doc/asio/reference/experimental__co_composed.html) offers examples for manual and implicit cancellation checking for an echo protocol. `co_composed` uses some magic `auto state` object for cancellation checking though, which I'm guessing is a wrapper around a `cancellation_slot` somewhere.